# How do I update a value on a page instantly (or ASAP) when it's updated in MySQL database? (without refresh)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Is there a way to pull a value from a MySQL database instantly (or within a second or less) when it is updated and display it on a page without refreshing the page?

The idea is that 2 people sitting at their computers are "racing" to update the value and whoever does it first "wins".  If User A clicks a link first, the value will update and User B will see the number change from 0 to 1 and his ability to click the link will disappear.

I am good with clicking a link to change the value from 0 to 1, but I'm not sure how to make the value instantly change for the other guy once the value has already been changed.

I'm starting to think this is just a bad idea for a web app.  Regardless, I'd like to know how to do it if it's possible.

Comment: you can do this using javascript & ajax. I have little experience with it - take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: with js you cannot communicate from one browser to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be possible with mysql. As mysql does not support realtime communication, it needs something like websockets.

Comment: Johannes Mittendorfer, I did a search for "websockets" (which I never heard of) and found Ratchet.  This is a technology I've never heard of.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll be looking into this!